# Is the Bengali translation of Padma Purana available online

Tags: puranas, translation-request, gita

I am searching for authentic Bengali translation of Padma Purana with Sanskrit sources, specifically the portion of Uttar Khand containing Glorification of Srimadvagabad Gita (Chapter 175-192, Part.VIII & IX of N.A.Deshpande's English translation). I have uploaded the relevant portion (English) [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5q8Hf9kt6y4Y043OFd2YVVrUHc/view?usp=sharing). If Bengali translation is unavailable online then can any linguistic scholar help me by translating it.

Comment: The zip file contains Padma Purana in 6 parts with Sanskrit slokas printed in Bengali script only. No translation. I will now try to get a copy of the physical book.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't realize that.

Comment: Does this question qualify for meta site or hinduism SE?

Comment: @Keshav I am waiting for the physical copy, compare the translation there w.r.t. english version, then decide about acceptance of answer. Be patient please.

Comment: The physical book published by Bhaktivedanta Book Trust contains four Gitamahatmyas translated in Bengali - 1)by Sri Shankaracharya, 2)from Skanda Purana, Avanti Khanda, 3)from Vaishnabiya-tantra-sara and 4)from Padma Purana, Uttar Khanda. Fourth one is a semantic translation without sanskrit verses. So my question is partially answered.

Comment: @Debanjan Good, I'm glad to hear it.  What do you mean by a semantic translation?  Do you mean a prose translation as opposed to a verse-by-verse translation?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Both paraphrasing & literal translation has been done to convey the meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlast I got a physical copy of authentic book of Padmapurana with both Sanskrit verses and corresponding Bengali translations. It matches with the English version I uploaded earlier. I have scanned & uploaded the relevant portion [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5q8Hf9kt6y4ZkFCUzVGQjBBckU/view?usp=sharing) as I reasonably feel the copyright has expired. Gradually I have uploaded the contents in Unicode Bengali in my Hindu religious [blog](http://bengali-gita.blogspot.com/2015/04/padmapuran-1.html). So my main question is now fully answered. Thank you Keshav'ji for helping me get the answer. The complete reference is:-
"Padmapuran, Uttarkhanda (Bengali)" by Veda Vyas, translated by Sri Tarakanta Debasharrma, Krishnadas Shastri and Sriramdas Shastri, edited by Pandit Panchanan Tarkaratna. Bangabasi-Electro-machine edition, 1915. Published & printed by Sri Natabar Chakraborty for Bangabasi Karyalay, 38/2 Bhabanicaran Datta Street, Kolkata. First Nababharat Edition, 2013 (with identical page layout). Nababharat Publishers, 72 D, Mahatma Gandhi Road, Kolkata-700009. 1062p.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [this ZIP file](http://www.oneallah.org/downloads/PadmaPuran.zip) contains a Bengali translation of the Padma Purana in PDF format; I can't tell, because I can't read either Bengali or Devanagari script.  Also, the Bhagavad Gita Mahatmya of the Padma Purana is available in Bengali as a physical book [here](http://www.indiabbt.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=417&category_id=7&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=1).